# RuntimeException when testing ListPreference with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to unit test my `PreferenceFragment` with Robolectric 3.0-RC3. My preferences are defined in a `preferences.xml` file and there are several `ListPreference`.

When I start testing my fragment with `FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(fragment)`, the method `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)` is called in the `onCreate` method of my `PreferenceFragment`.

And I get the following exception:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? ResName{com.myapp:array/pageOrientation_entries}
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:99)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.Converter.convertAndFill(Converter.java:50)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.createTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:232)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.attrsToTypedArray(ShadowResources.java:209)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.access$000(ShadowResources.java:55)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources$ShadowTheme.obtainStyledAttributes(ShadowResources.java:485)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java)
    at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:472)
    at android.preference.ListPreference.**constructor**(ListPreference.java:49)
    at android.preference.ListPreference.(ListPreference.java)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:299)
    at com.myapp.ui.settings.SettingsFragment.onCreate(SettingsFragment.java:53)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:29)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postAtFrontOfQueue(Scheduler.java:98)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:114)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
    at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
    at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1358)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:728)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:704)
    at org.robolectric.util.FragmentTestUtil.startFragment(FragmentTestUtil.java:14)
    at com.myapp.ui.settings.SettingsFragmentTest.startFragment(SettingsFragmentTest.java:40)
    at com.myapp.ui.settings.SettingsFragmentTest.plusFeaturesDisabled_onSignaturePrefClick(SettingsFragmentTest.java:70)
    ... 18 more

When I comment out all the `ListPreference`and leave the other kinds of preferences, I don't have this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Robolectric 3.0 has an issue to handle generic array resources like:

```
<array>
  <item>Option 1</item>
</array>
```

In my case I could fix the issue by explicitly change it to the correct array type:

```
<string-array>
  <item>Option 1</item>
</string-array>
```